# Jquery DataTable : Table Inside TD, Sub Table, Nested Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatable where I need to show a table inside td cell, I have checked drill down example but that requires click on the plus sign, apart that is viewed below the row that contains plus sign. That is not required

I want to create exact nested table like
[image]

where td cell have one nested table inline and no need to click on any plus sign.
Using datatable is this possible? Any reference please?

Comment: Dont think so. jQuery DataTables does not support colspans or rowspans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Datatable` offers basic support for complex headers :

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Otherwise, you can use callbacks to have your table render something more complicated than single adjacent cells.

http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks

Look for `fnDrawCallback` and `fnRowCallback`

The following example will not achieve what you want, but will give you an example of how you can manipulate the html each time `datatables` modifies it (using `fnDrawCallback`) :

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Here is a basic example for using `fnRowCallback` :

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html

A piece of warning though : if you start fiddling with the table structure, you may end up with surprises with the "filter" and "sort" functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used "createdRow" Callback function of Datatables.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var tb = "<table><tr><td>td1</td><td>td2</td></tr><tr><td>td1</td><td>td2</td></tr></table>";
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
                   $('td', row).eq(5).html(tb);                  
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        td.highlight {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
```